# Activity to fragment 1, fragment 1 to fragment 2 fragment 2 to Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am beginner in Android development. I am creating a small application in which i call two fragment from single activity. 
Activity -> fragment 1->fragment 2.

Activity to fragment 1, fragment 1 to fragment 2.
 I want to know how i directly call fragment 2 to Activity directly.

I give button in Fragment 2, on click of that button I want go in Activity.

Comment: Don't do fragment transaction inside fragment, you should write one interface and implement that in your activity and do your fragment transaction there itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activity already exists. Your activity is the one hosting the fragments i.e assuming all are full screen fragments, when you call fragment1, your activity removes the present fragment (if there is any) and replaces it with fragment1, when you call fragment2, fragment1 is replaced with fragment2 and so on.

If you want to see only the layout of the activity (which in most cases would be just a white screen), you have to remove all fragments, to do that, add this to your button's onClick:

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack(1, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

By your question I notice that you still need to read about fragments.
you can't go to an activity from a fragment because the fragments
are a section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, you can add or remove them while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

Although you can replace a fragment and use a different one on the same activity.
you can do so like this:

1. First in main xml use a layout that your going to inflate:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:id="@+id/frgContainer"
   android:layout_margin="20dp"
   android:background="#00e6ff">
   ```

   ```
      <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/btn"
       android:text="btn"
       />
       </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Create 2 new activities which will be our fragments with an xml files you can add anything you wish to it:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context="com.example.hackeru.mydynamicfragment.Login">

   <EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:hint="User Name"
   android:id="@+id/txtLoginUser"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
   android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
   android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
   />

   <EditText
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:hint="Password"
   android:id="@+id/txtLoginPass"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
   />

   <Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
   android:text="Login"
   />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Override onCreate method on the fragment

   ```
   public class Login extends Fragment {
   @Nullable
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login,container,false);
   }
   ```

4.use fragmentTransaction in the onClick method in main to replace or add current layout with the fragment you created:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             FragmentManager fragmentManager =getFragmentManager();
        // we must handle the callback fragment process
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Login loginFragment = new Login();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frgContainer,loginFragment);
         //  fragmentTransaction.replace if there is another fragment you
         //  wish to replace
        fragmentTransaction.commit(); 
}
```

read this:

## https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html